# Redirect to new page and set POST data

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect

I am trying to redirect to a new web site and set post data to be sent to that website. I tried this:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(302, {"Location": "http://example.com/newpage/", "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"});
    res.end("param1=value1&param2=value2");
}).listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
```

This is unsuccessful. How can I redirect to a new website and set POST data?

Answer (score 0):

Simple redirect cannot send with post data.
You have to make a new request and pipe to original request

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var http = require('http');

  var post_data = JSON.stringify({aaa: 'abc', bbb: 123});

  var options = {
    host: 'example.com',
    port: '80',
    path: '/',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Content-Length': post_data.length
  };


  var req = http.request(options, function(resp_new) {
    resp_new.setEncoding('utf8');

    resp_new.on('data', function(chunk){
      res.send(chunk);
    });

    resp_new.on('end', function(){
      res.end();
    });
  }); 

  req.write(post_data);
  req.end();
});
```